# getting issue in simple filter ag-grid in reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am facing issue in simple filter when i click And and Or radio buttons both buttons remained select. I want to fix this issue. Please help me .[simple filter issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtMG7.png)

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is now impossible to tell what might be the problem since we do not know how you implemented this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help get through your problem.

```
    this.state = {
      name: "React"
    };
    this.onValueChange = this.onValueChange.bind(this);
    this.formSubmit = this.formSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onValueChange(event) {
   this.setState({
      selectedOption: event.target.value
    });
  }

  formSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.selectedOption)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>
        <div className="radio">
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="AND"
              checked={this.state.selectedOption === "AND"}
              onChange={this.onValueChange}
            />
            AND
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="radio">
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="OR"
              checked={this.state.selectedOption === "OR"}
              onChange={this.onValueChange}
            />
            OR
          </label>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry to say this is not the solution. any body here who has ag-grid experience.

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem in more detail? or add at least  minimal reproducible sample

Comment: i m giving you screen shot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtMG7.png

Comment: You should provide any minimalist example of your code, how does someone know that what are you doing wrong?